# Unattended Chats - Live Agent

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

Is there a way to know in Live Agent how many unattended chats there were per day?

Thanks in advanced.
Juliette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by running a report agains the Live Chat Transcript and filtering to only show records in which Status = "Missed".

If you cannot see the Live Chat Transcript as an option on the first step of Report building (when selecting the Report Type), then you will need to create a custom report type by following this help article: [How To Create a Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&language=en_US)

For step # 3 you will want to select Live Chat Transcript.

Once you have the Report Type, you will be able to create the report. Here is a screenshot example of how I created mine.

[image]

Good Luck!!

Luis Luciani